# How to find whether a camera app is running in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera, android-service

I'm a newbie to android

Basically I want your suggestions on how to find whether the current running foreground application is a camera app (both native and third party) from a background service.

I'm able to get the current running activity's class name and package name using following code snippet,

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
Log.d("TopActivity", "Class Name:" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
Log.d("TopActivity", "Package Name:" + componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

and the results for various camera apps are,

```
Native Camera
D/TopActivity(23237): Class Name: com.lge.camera.CameraAppLauncher
D/TopActivity(23237): Package Name: com.lge.camera

Google Camera
D/TopActivity(23237): Class Name: com.android.camera.CameraLauncher
D/TopActivity(23237): Package Name: com.google.android.GoogleCamera

Cartoon Camera
D/TopActivity(23237): Class Name: com.fingersoft.camera.MainActivity
D/TopActivity(23237): Package Name: com.fingersoft.cartooncamera

QR Droid - Scan
D/TopActivity(23237): Class Name: la.droid.qr.DeCamara
D/TopActivity(23237): Package Name: la.droid.qr

Little Photo - Camera App
D/TopActivity(23237): Class Name: com.littlephoto.TakeActivity
D/TopActivity(23237): Package Name: com.littlephoto
```

As you can see, from logs its not possible to find whether the app is camera or not.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "I'm able to get the current running activity's class name and package name using following code snippet" -- note that `getRunningTasks()` is deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next Android release. This method will only return tasks associated with your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @CommonsWare So there's no other way do it ?